# What is the appropriate way to train a face detector / classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, classification

I want to build a face detector/classifier to generate a network that detects whether a face is present in an image/video.

I understand the basic concept, but what I have problems with is the choice of the number of classes.
Initially, I thought that two classes (with face / without face) would be sufficient. However, I was unsure which data I should use for the class 'without face'. So I threw together datasets of equipment and plants and animals, whereupon the classes were very unbalanced, which is apparently not good.
Then I thought it would be better to use as many classes as possible.

But again, I am unsure what would be the best/common approach to the problem?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro & **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: Wrong site for this question. Also, the negative cases should contain pictures of people where face isn't visible e.g. hidden, cropped, back of head and positive cases should contain pictures of animal faces too. You'll should also include rotated images. Try asking in datascience stack exchange site. Also, you could use different regions of the same photos for different labels.

Comment: Agreed that this is the wrong site, I'll just leave one tip: Think about your application. Don't just "train a model". The correct approach will depend heavily on how the system will be used later. If it won't actually be used anywhere -- great, use this opportunity to just try different options and see how they behave, you will learn a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can experiment with any number of samples and different images for the negative class. If the datasets with equipment/plant/places you have are imbalanced, you can try to subsample, e.g. pick 100 images from each.

Just don't make the negative class too huge, w.r.t the number of images with human samples you have. The rest is up to experimentation.